# Just installed Visual Studio Community 2017, but cannot find CLR

Tags: visual-studio, c++

I'm trying to create a form (following some basic tutorials), but I cannot find the CLR option under Visual C++ node.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Launch again the **VS 2017 Installer** and in the **Desktop development with C++** select to the right the Optional component "C++ /CLI Support":[image: VSC]

Source: [Visual Studio 2017 - CLR Missing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e22b3e41-c087-433e-be36-ea312984c9b4/visual-studio-2017-clr-missing?forum=visualstudiogeneral)